# random image swip in iPhone

Tags: iphone, image

I have to generate random number between 11 to 20 and store it in button.Every time random number is generated and random number of time two images are swipe in iPhone
for instance if random number is 12 then image swipe 12 times and then swipe will be stopped.

I have generated random numbers but can't swipe images w.r.t random numbers.

Here is my code

```
-(IBAction)btngeneratePressed:(id)sender{



number = 1 + arc4random() % 10 + 10;


for (int j=1;j<number-1;j++)  // generate unique random number only once
{



    NSArray *myImageNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1.png", @"2.png", nil];
    //int index = arc4random() % [myImageNames count];

    int index = arc4random() % 2;

    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[myImageNames objectAtIndex:index]];
    img.image = myImage;




    if(number == j){

        NSLog(@"Number %d ",j);

        UIAlertView *someError = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Rendom number" message: @"Image swip" delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [someError show];
        [someError release];
        break;


    }

}
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    number = 1 + arc4random() % 10 + 10;


    NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",number];


    int p=string;




    label.text = string;




    for(int j=1;j<number-1;j++)

    {   



        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                                                         action:@selector(btngeneratePressed:)]; 
        [recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)];
        recognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
        recognizer.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
        [recognizer release];    

        //Add a right swipe gesture recognizer
        recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                               action:@selector(btngeneratePressed:)];
        recognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
        recognizer.delegate = self;

        [recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
        [recognizer release]; 


        if(number == j){

            NSLog(@"Number %d ",j);

            UIAlertView *someError = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Rendom number" message: @"Image swip" delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];

            [someError show];
            [someError release];
            break;

        }




    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand what you are trying to do, but I would approach the problem by breaking it into chunks, rather than trying to do it all at once, and all jumbled up.

Sort out the psedo-random unique number generator as once task and encapsulate it in a class/method.
Work out how to swipe images and catch/count single, and then multiple, swipes
Sort out the image display 
Wire it all together

As it stands you're generating number-1 swipe gesture recognizers, which is definitely not right. You want one of each.

You're regenerating all of the images each time you call btngeneratePressed: which is definitely inefficient, and slow.

Break the problem down into discrete parts and solve each to build towards the final solution you need.